# import error (JSONField) with djangorestframework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm trying to add REST support to an existing (somewhat old) django project. Following instrucions here http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/ I added the line

```
from rest_framework import routers
```

to the file `urls.py`. But then I get this error:

```
File "/Users/paolini/piprints/cvgmt/urls.py" in <module>
  8. from rest_framework import routers
File "/Users/paolini/.virtualenvs/cvgmt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py" in <module>
  24. from rest_framework import views
File "/Users/paolini/.virtualenvs/cvgmt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in <module>
  21. from rest_framework.response import Response
File "/Users/paolini/.virtualenvs/cvgmt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py" in <module>
  13. from rest_framework.serializers import Serializer
File "/Users/paolini/.virtualenvs/cvgmt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in <module>
  1534.     ModelSerializer.serializer_field_mapping[postgres_fields.JSONField] = JSONField

Exception Type: AttributeError at /
Exception Value: 'module' object has no attribute 'JSONField'
```

Don't know how to handle this. The error seems to be in the libraries, not my code.

djangorestframework==3.7.1
Django==1.8.8

Comment: What version of django rest framework and django are you using?

Comment: djangorestframework==3.7.1

Comment: and django version?

Comment: Sorry: Django==1.8.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for django 1.8 was dropped since version 3.7. Either update your django version or downgrade restframework whatever works for you best.

More info [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/release-notes/#370)